# Uploading files using PHP `$_FILES` is not set?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I've been developing a plugin for WordPress.
As I already have made an application which uploads files for me, I thought it would be easy but alas, I can't think of what I am doing wrong.

The problem is; my `$_FILES['image']` is not set.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code, because I can't find out what it is.

**Form**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table class="table ws-form-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Add Text:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="ws-text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ws-add-text ws-add-button">+</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Add Image:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="image"><progress></progress>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ws-add-image ws-add-button">+</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="preview-container">
                <div class="preview-strict">
                    <img class="ws-image" src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" alt="" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('.ws-add-image').click(function() {
    var formData = new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);
    console.log('Click Initiated');
    console.log('Ajax Try...');
    jQuery.ajax({

        url: '../../wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin-handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ 
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },

        data: formData,

        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        error: function() {
            console.log('Error Initiated');
        },
    }).done(function() {
        alert('dsa');
        jQuery('.preview-strict').prepend('<div id="dragHelper" style="display:inline-block; z-index: 999; cursor: move;"><img id="theImg" src="../../wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/' + readCookie('image') + '" width="200px" height=200px; /></div>');
        jQuery("#dragHelper").draggable({drag: function(){
            var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            jQuery('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            jQuery('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
        });

        jQuery("#theImg").resizable();

    });
    alert(readCookie('image'));
    console.log('Done!');
});
function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        jQuery('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my-plugin"; 

if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $wty = 'ISSET';
      $sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM " . $table_name . " ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
      echo $_FILES['image']['name'];
      foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM " . $table_name . " ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1") as $key => $row) {
          $id = $row->ID;
      }

      $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
      $last = $id . round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $ext = end((explode(".", $file_name)));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(empty($errors)==true) {

         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, ABSPATH . "test/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/" . $last);

      }

      else

      {

         print_r($errors);

      }
}


$cookie_name = "image";
$cookie_value = $wty;
$cookie_exp = time() + (86400 * 30);



setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_exp, "/");


?>
```

So this is how it works: Image gets chosen, button gets clicked, click event runs, ajax runs a PHP file. The PHP file (needs to) upload image, creates cookie with image name. Image name gets pulled from cookie, and adds it to the DOM after ajax done.

I've tried to look this up but for some reason I can't find anything but peoples saying that I might be forgetting `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

So what am I doing wrong?

Keep in mind that this is a WordPress plugin. So it may be something WordPress related. But I don't think so.

I'm still learning so any help with improving the code is appreciated!

Comment: Place this `print_r($_FILES)` in your PHP file.What do you get ?

Comment: @AliN11, an empty array unfortunately. The thing is, it is really hard to tell whether it works or not because I can't see any error's or any echo's on the form page.

Comment: `jQuery('form')[0]` does that return the actual form your file input is in? If there are other form elements in the page before the one you actually want it might be getting one of those. Have you checked the request headers to make sure you are sending a file, ie in your Network tab in your browsers developers tools look for the request to your endpoint and look at the payload to see if it lists a file.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, alright I checked it and it send a file. Seemed that my code is (partially) correct. Because of the code Sanjay gave me, it showed me that the path was incorrect. So I have changed this. Plus that the $_FILE IS set. The problem was that the cookie takes the variable from last upload. So it looked like the variable stayed the same at first. Which is why I thought it doesnt set. I just have to change the way I show my cookie so it shows me the correct variable... It was a long day -.- Thank you very much though for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for single or multiple files.

```
$('.ws-add-image').click(function() {

 var data = new FormData();

 //Append files infos
 jQuery.each($(this)[0].files, function(i, file) {
     data.append('file-'+i, file);
 });

 $.ajax({  
     url: "my_path",  
     type: "POST",  
     data: data,  
     cache: false,
     processData: false,  
     contentType: false, 
     context: this,
     success: function (msg) {
          alert(msg);
      }
  });
});
```

Then in your php file you will get file using..

```
$_FILES['file-0']
$_FILES['file-1']
```

Comment: `.ws-add-image` is a button so `$(this)[0]` is going to be the button DOM element which doesn't have a `files` property. Also OP's use of `new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);` will, if selecting the correct form element, automatically add inputs to the formdata object

Comment: Sanjay thank you very much for leading me into the right direction! Your code showed me that it was the wrong path I gave up. All in all, it is fixed! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing following while cooking up your AJAX request:

```
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately, it did not do anything for me. Because the code you can see I have posted, is actually copied and pasted. This code is from a working upload function. The only thing that I changed are paths. But if you have any other suggestions, I'm up for it!

Comment: FormData objects automatically adds all of a forms inputs when the constructor is passed a form DOM element which OP has done: `new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);`